# Change randomly indexed vowel in a string:bound must be positive

Tags: java, arrays, random, indexoutofboundsexception, illegalargumentexception

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;


 public class MachinePedagogy {


     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         changeVowel("dictionary.txt");

}
private static void changeVowel(String path) throws IOException {
    char ch;

    BufferedWriter bWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("changevowel.txt")));
    String aeiou = "aeiou";
    char[] vowels = aeiou.toCharArray();
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));
    for(String temp = bReader.readLine(); temp != null; temp = bReader.readLine()){
        int counter = 0;
        char[] characters = temp.toCharArray();
            for(int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++){

                ch = temp.charAt(i);


                if(
                ch == 'a' || 
                ch == 'e' || 
                ch == 'i' || 
                ch == 'o' || 
                ch == 'u'){
                    counter++;
                    }
                }
            Random rand = new Random();
            int vIndex[] = new int[counter];
            int index = 0;  
            for (int j = 0; j <temp.length(); j++){
                ch = temp.charAt(j);
                if(
                        ch == 'a' || 
                        ch == 'e' || 
                        ch == 'i' || 
                        ch == 'o' || 
                        ch == 'u'){
                    vIndex[index] = j;
                    index++;
                }
            }
            int random2 = (rand.nextInt(vIndex.length));
            int random1 = (rand.nextInt(vowels.length));
            characters[vIndex[random2]] = vowels[random1];
            temp = String.valueOf(characters);
        bWriter.write(temp + "\n");
    }
    bReader.close();
    bWriter.close();
     }
 }
```

Why is my bound sometimes negative on these arrays?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at MachinePedagogy.changeVowel(MachinePedagogy.java:56)
at MachinePedagogy.main(MachinePedagogy.java:14)
```

line 56:

```
characters[vIndex[random2]] = vowels[random1];
```

Line 14:

```
changeVowel("dictionary.txt");
```

I want to edit a random vowel in a string and change it to another random vowel, preferably different from what it was previously. [Dictionary.txt](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/assignments/dictionary.txt) is just a Stanford dictionary if you need that to compile the code.

Many examples I have found in replacing vowels follow this logic.

```
temp.replaceAll( "[aeiou]", "?" );
```

I don't want to replace all the vowels, just a single randomly indexed vowel. I think it might have something to do with nextInt() but I am confused when I read the documentation [Random#nextInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) as to why that might be. What I have read from other StackOverflow questions asked is that this is a valid way of producing random indexes for an array.

**I wrote a spell checker and want to test its capabilities for accuracy with a commonly made error of changing a single vowel of a word. I plan on removing correct words from the big list that I've created by running the changevowel.txt against dictionary.txt later & removing correct words from changevowel.txt but that is unimportant to the immediate problem at hand.**

Comment: Um. What is the question?

Comment: Why is my bound sometimes negative on these arrays?

Comment: Please add that to the OP. Also, how are you determining that the bounds are negative? Through a debugger? Or are you just seeing the exception? Either way, provide a spot in the code that specifically identifies the problem

Comment: I apologize Ben, I'm still new here and trying to do everything correctly and orderly to what I see others who seem to ask good questions.

I see the exception in the console in Eclipse after I run it.

Comment: Don't worry about getting it all right. It takes time. Let's take a look at the StackTrace

Comment: Which line is 56? Please mark it so we can all find it.

Comment: Also, from your error message it appears that whatever you pass to Random#nextInt() isn't >= 0, which is possible if your `counter` variable never increments (never finds a vowel) and then causes `vIndex.length` to be 0

Comment: Thank you Shar1er, Weston and Ben for your feedback. This was all very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
>   at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)

Is not from this line `characters[vIndex[random2]] = vowels[random1];`

But this line:

```
int random2 = (rand.nextInt(vIndex.length));
```

`rand.nextInt`'s argument must be `> 0`, but `vIndex.length == 0` somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Give this logic a try:

- Get all the indexes of vowels out of the word
- Choose a random vowel index and get it out of the word
- Choose another random vowel from a "vowels list" that is not the same from the previous step
- Replace the chosen random vowel with the new random vowel

Example:

```
static String vowels = "AEIOU";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String word = "MIRACULOUSNESS";
    char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();

    Random rand = new Random();
    List<Integer> vowelIndexes = getVowelIndexes(word);

    // Choose random vowel index and get the random vowel from the word
    int randomVowelIndex = vowelIndexes.get(rand.nextInt(vowelIndexes.size()));
    char randomVowel = word.charAt(randomVowelIndex);

    // Choose random vowel replacement that isn't the same as the randomVowel
    char replacementVowel = randomVowel;
    while (replacementVowel == randomVowel) {
        replacementVowel = vowels.charAt(rand.nextInt(vowels.length()));
    }

    System.out.printf("Before: %s\n", word);

    // Replace the vowel
    wordArray[randomVowelIndex] = replacementVowel;
    word = new String(wordArray);

    System.out.printf("After : %s\n", word);
}

public static List<Integer> getVowelIndexes(String word) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (vowels.contains(""+word.charAt(i))) {
            result.add(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Results (Varies on each run):

```
Before: MIRACULOUSNESS
After : MIRECULOUSNESS
```